# Validação Javascript de um campo multiple

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou com problema para validar os arquivos de um `input` do tipo `file` que tem um array e também é um `multiple`. Como na função abaixo a variavel **nomearquivo** só me devolve o nome do primeiro arquivo sendo que existem outros 3 ou podem até ser mais. Alguém já passou por isso?

```
 function envia(){

        var nomearquivo = document.getElementById('file').value;

        var valor = nomearquivo.split("-");

        var data = valor[0].slice(-8);

        var n = data.split("");

        var databr = n[0]+n[1]+'/'+n[2]+n[3]+'/'+n[4]+n[5]+n[6]+n[7];

       var valida = valida_data_novo(databr);

         if(valida){

    document.forms[0].submit();

    }

  }

  <INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="arquivo[]" ID="file" multiple/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A validação para arquivos é um pouco diferente encontrei vários metodos e consegui solucionar meu problema.

```
  var fileInput = document.getElementById ("file");

  if ('files' in fileInput){

          for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {

              var file = fileInput.files[i];

              var file = file.name;

              var valor = file.split("-");

              var data = valor[0].slice(-8);

              var n = data.split("");

              var databr = n[0]+n[1]+'/'+n[2]+n[3]+'/'+n[4]+n[5]+n[6]+n[7];

              var valida = val_data_multiarq(databr,file);

          }
      }
```